# cannot touch file: No such file or directory for a specific file

Tags: linux, files, touch

I know you have had many other doubts related to this same issue, but I have not found anything that would allow me to reproduce the same case that I had.

The situation is simple, I can do this:

```
$ touch example1.txt
```

but I can't do this:

```
$ touch example2.txt
touch: cannot touch 'example2.txt': No such file or directory
```

In this case, both `example1.txt` and `example2.txt` are files created via software, and we know that at some point the `example2.txt` file was probably created (the file names have a specific configuration formed by letters and numbers, without characters special spaces or blanks).

We are no longer able to obtain more information about the server that generated this situation (it is a client's server and we have already solved the situation in another way, creating another directory to store the files), but what I couldn't find out is what happened.

Even with root, we were unable to create the file (`mkdir example2.txt`, `rm -rf example2.txt`, result in the same error, `ls -laF` does not display the file).

The directory is shared via samba with Windows machines, and we think it might have something to do with it, but we tried in many ways to reproduce a similar case without success.

Now I'm really asking out of curiosity, because I tried to generate a similar situation and I couldn't.

Basically what I'm looking for is a way to reproduce the situation, and a way to resolve it (to deal with the situation in the software, if possible, or if not possible, then generate a log for the server administrator to resolve quickly).

In case anyone has any idea how to reproduce a similar situation, I would be grateful to share.

The directory was in `/tmp/software_files`, and we were able to create any file or directory inside, only the `example2.txt` file generated this situation.

Comment: Are `example1.txt` and `example2.txt` the actual names you used, or did you translate the real names for the sake of the question?  If you did translate them, can you share the real name of `example2.txt`?

Comment: yes they are examples only, the files follow a format like:
ArchiveECD01012020.txt

In this case what changes is just the date, ArchiveECD + ddmmyyyy.txt

ArchiveECD01012020.txt - OK
ArchiveECD01032020.txt - OK
ArchiveECD01042020.txt - Fail
ArchiveECD01092020.txt - OK

Comment: Did you ever got an solution? I'm facing this problem and will appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
mkdir test && cd test && rm -r ../test && touch fail; cd
touch: cannot touch 'fail': No such file or directory
```

or

```
touch other/fail
touch: cannot touch 'other/fail': No such file or directory
```

You could check for that but it's better to use a trap

```
if [ ! -d "$(pwd)" ] ; then echo fail; fi
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, but this would not be the case. The directory in question existed and it was possible to create any other files or directories in it, only one of the files (in this case, depending on the name of the file) has this problem.